# How to handle the lifetimes of two fltk buttons that toggle eachother?

Tags: rust, event-handling, lifetime, fltk

I'm trying to create two buttons (btn1, btn2) handling events (simple 'push' aka 'onclick'), they should disable each other

```
let mut btn1 = button::Button::new(100, 100, 100, 50, "BTN1");
let mut btn2 = button::Button::new(300, 100, 150, 50, "BTN2");

// handle btn1 click
btn1.handle(move |thisBtn, evt| match evt {
    enums::Event::Push => {
        clicked(thisBtn, &mut btn2);
        true
    }
    _ => false,
});

// handle btn2 click
btn2.handle(move |thisBtn, evt| match evt {
    enums::Event::Push => {
        clicked(thisBtn, &mut btn1);
        true
    }
    _ => false,
});

// both buttons should be mutable, or activate/deactivate wont work
fn clicked(thisBtn: &mut button::Button, otherBtn: &mut button::Button) {
    thisBtn.deactivate();
    otherBtn.activate();
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `btn2`
  --> src\main.rs:18:5
   |
6  |       let mut btn2 = button::Button::new(300, 100, 150, 50, "BTN2");
   |           -------- move occurs because `btn2` has type `Button`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
9  |       btn1.handle(move |thisBtn, evt| match evt {
   |                   ------------------- value moved into closure here
10 |           enums::Event::Push => {
11 |               clicked(thisBtn, &mut btn2);
   |                                     ---- variable moved due to use in closure
...
18 | /     btn2.handle(move |thisBtn, evt| match evt {
19 | |         enums::Event::Push => {
20 | |             clicked(thisBtn, &mut btn1);
21 | |             true
22 | |         }
23 | |         _ => false,
24 | |     });
   | |______^ value borrowed here after move

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Okay, I understand that I move the borrowed btn2 so later I can't use it again. So I tried to remove `move` so btn2 stays in the current scope, but failed:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `btn2`, which is owned by the current function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the classic case for `Rc<RefCell<T>>`:

```rust
let btn1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(button::Button::new(100, 100, 100, 50, "BTN1")));
let btn2 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(button::Button::new(300, 100, 150, 50, "BTN2")));
let (btn1_clone, btn2_clone) = (Rc::clone(&btn1), Rc::clone(&btn2));
btn1.borrow_mut().handle(move |this_btn, evt| match evt {
    enums::Event::Push => {
        clicked(this_btn, &mut *btn2_clone.borrow_mut());
        true
    }
    _ => false,
});
btn2.borrow_mut().handle(move |this_btn, evt| match evt {
    enums::Event::Push => {
        clicked(this_btn, &mut *btn1_clone.borrow_mut());
        true
    }
    _ => false,
});
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer! However, I cant compile it, because RC::clone cant copy buttons, so it just moves it, and the magic doesnt happen https://prnt.sc/249g2bd

Comment: @fewrandom Shouldn't the second closure use `btn1_clone`?

Comment: @fewrandom @kmdreko is right, you use `btn2_clone` twice instead of once for `btn1_clone` and once for `btn2_clone`.

Comment: @fewrandom Each `Rc` clone can be moved only once, but `Rc` can be cloned as many times as you want.

Comment: yes, indeed, my bad sorry, now everything works, thanks guys! <3